# Contact sync not working

Tags: 2013-sp1, audience-manager, contact-sync

We are using SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 with Oracle 12c as the CM and CD database. Recently we noticed that contact sync is not working. We are using Java on the presentation side.

Audience Manager Sync log on the CMS shows the below error:

```
2017-03-25T15:05:14 [Info] Starting synchronization cycle to: http://my.presentation.server/outbound_email/profilesync.jsp
2017-03-25T15:05:14 [Info] Synchronizing to management system
2017-03-25T15:05:14 [Trace] Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.SynchronizationServer.Process()  
2017-03-25T15:05:14 [Trace] Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.SynchronizationServer.Process()  
2017-03-25T15:05:14 [Trace] Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.SynchronizationServer.Process()  
2017-03-25T15:05:14 [Trace] Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.SynchronizationServer.Process()  
2017-03-25T15:05:14 [Trace] Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.SynchronizationServer.Process()  
2017-03-25T15:05:14 [Trace] Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.SynchronizationServer.SynchronizeToContentManager()  
2017-03-25T15:05:15 [Error] Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: String
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Synchronization.SynchronizationBatch.Deserialize(XmlReader reader)
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Synchronization.SynchronizationBatch.Process(Boolean deserializePsResponse)
   at Tridion.OutboundEmail.Services.Synchronizer.PsToCmSynchronizationTask.SynchronizeToContentManager(UserContext userContext, Boolean& workProcessedSuccesfully)
   at Tridion.OutboundEmail.Services.Synchronizer.PsToCmSynchronizationTask.Process()
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Utilities.OutboundEmailServiceBase`1.Process(UserContext userContext)`
```

Comment: If you go to http://my.presentation.server/outbound_email/profilesync.jsp in your browser, does it perform a test of your configuration and report success? From the error, it seems like AM is receiving a different response than expected so there might be something else interfering (like a firewall or other security-related software running on your network)

Comment: Sending a GET request to the profile sync page in the browser shows no config errors. I get the standard response. Does not seem like a firewall issue.

Comment: It's still possible that it's some security software; for example if it only interferes when the request is a POST. But you know better if you have anything like that :) Anyway, have you checked the log files on the CD environment?

Comment: @PeterKjaer no errors in the CD log files. No security software (firewall or antivirus) between the CM and CD.

Comment: Is there *any* evidence of the synchronization happening in the CD logs (you might have to increase the log level)? I'm wondering if it is contacting the right endpoint...

Comment: @PeterKjaer From the CD access logs I can see the incoming requests to the profilesync.jsp page, so the CMS is definitely polling the correct the sync target for syncing.

Comment: Is there any chance that the profile sync JAR files have not been updated to the 2013 SP1 version? That would explain why it seems to go fine but it's having trouble parsing the XML on the CM side.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly due to mismatch in the Extension fields between CM and CD database. Check whether any extended fields definition is missing in the Content Manager Database.

Comment: the fields are the same and there is no mismatch. it was all working fine up until a couple days back.

Comment: Did you check if your sync (profile/sync etc.. ) services are running and the ports they use are correctly configured..? For the matter of fact don't forget to restart your CMs once..

Comment: services are running and the ports are correctly configured. already restarted CMS twice.